# Requesting an API

Tags: php, request

I am making http requests to an API with curl:

```
$data = '{"id": 1}';
$ch = curl_init('https://localhost:8888/products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$products = json_decode($result, true);
```

This code works but I'm refactoring my code and I was wondering if is there any library to make the same in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php-curl-class for an Object Oriented approach:

https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

Makes things a bit easier.